# How to show a tooltip on a tinymce textarea

Tags: jquery, html, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using jQuery(1.11.3) and Tinymce 4,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

The problem with tinymce library is that title attribute on `<textarea>` element doesn't work. I have tried to add the title with js, but nothing changed :

```
<textarea class="mce-editor" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tooltip message" required></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

When TinyMCE is invoked the textarea itself is no longer visible.  TinyMCE will inject a bunch of HTML/CSS/JS including an iFrame for the content of the editor.

If you look at the full content that is injected perhaps you could add a title to one of them.

Once TinyMCE is loaded look in the browser's dev tools for the class `mce-tinymce` ... that is the root of what is injected.